# How to pass data to java application from a bash script correctly

Tags: java, bash, shell, ubuntu

I tried to collect some information about the system such as memory usage and cpu usage and pass it to a java application which is responsible to store it into a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you are on the right path on calling the java program with at the end of your bash script.

I am 99.9% sure you need to call `java -jar` not just `java` in your bash script.

```
java Program $perName $systemCpuUsage $systemMemoryUsage $readingTime

java -jar Program $perName $systemCpuUsage $systemMemoryUsage $readingTime
```

Also in your main java class I think your should call a for each statement instead of a fixed loop.

```
for(String arg : args)            
{   
     System.out.println(arg);            
}
```

And the only other thing I can think of is that there is something wrong with your bash script is not getting the variables correctly. You should try to `echo` out your results to debug what the variables are supposed to be in the bash script.

### EDIT

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means that your looping two many times. Replacing it with a for each will tell you how many variables were passed through. When you get that error it means that your args array is not big enough and your trying to get data from a section in your array that doesn't exists.